# Unique processes and threads in c

Tags: c, multithreading

For the program below:

```
int main() {
Pid_t pid1, pid2;
Pid1 = fork();
pid2 = fork();
if (pid1 == 0) { /* child process */
thread_create(. . .);
}
if (pid2 == 0) { /* child process */
pthread_create(. . .);
}
fork();
}
```

a.How many unique processes are created? 
b. How many unique threads are created?

Our class has been discussing this for two days. We are told that it is 2 unique threads. However when I replace the pthread_create with a print I am getting more than two. I get this output

Thread 2: 1855 0
Thread 1: 0 1859
Thread 1: 0 0
Thread 2: 0 0
Where Thread 1/2 shows the if statments and pid1 pid2 is printed.

So why is it 2? Can you provide an explanation we can show in class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first fork creates a second process from your first process. But the second fork is not guarded by checking the PID, so this fork happens in *both* processes, resulting in a total of 4 processes. The final fork at the end will then result in 8 processes.

So, when you read the if statements, you have 4 processes. Lets examine the pid values in these processes:

```
Process 1: Pid1=0, Pid2=0 
Process 2: Pid1=0, Pid2=non-0
Process 3: Pid1=non-0, Pid2=0
Process 4: Pid1=non-0, Pid2=non-0
```

You will see that process 1 will now create 2 threads. Process 2 will create 1 thread, process 3 will create 1 thread, and process 4 will create no threads.

> So why is it 2?

As we have seen, it is not. 4 new threads are created (for a total of 12 threads if we included the main thread of each process).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a "unique" thread is supposed to be in this context, but the number of processes created here is 8; We start with one process, the first fork creates another. Both of those hit the second fork, which creates 2 more processes, and finally all of those 4 hit the last fork making for 8 processes total.

The first `pthread_create` is hit by the second (first child of the first) process and the child of the second process, whereas the second `pthread_create` is hit by the child of the second process and the second child of the first process (be very skeptical about this paragraph, I got this mixed up in my head several times so I can see why you'd struggle with this).

So depending on what exactly you're counting, there are 8 "main" threads, 4 "auxiliary" threads or 12 threads total. Not sure how you're supposed to come up with 2, other than the trivial fact that there are 2 calls to `pthread_create` in the *source code*.

If you have a very particular definition of "unique thread" that would change this, please edit your answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You start with one process, call it PROCESS_A.

After the first `fork` call you have two processes, PROCESS_A (pid1 > 0) and PROCESS_B (pid1 = 0).

Both PROCESS_A and PROCESS_B then fork again, producing (in total) PROCESS_A, PROCESS_B, PROCESS_C, and PROCESS_D, so we end up with:

First `fork` situation:

> PROCESS_A (pid1 > 0, pid2 > 0) is the parent process of B.
>
> PROCESS_B (pid1 = 0, pid2 > 0) is a child of PROCESS_A (pid1 > 0)

Second `fork` situation:

> PROCESS_C (pid1 > 0 (copied from A), pid2 = 0) is a child of PROCESS_A (pid2 > 0)
>
> PROCESS_D (pid1 = 0 (copied from B), pid2 = 0) is a child of PROCESS_B (pid2 > 0).

Thus, in terms of thread creation:

> PROCESS_A doesn't create either thread, because both `pid1` and `pid2` are non-zero in PROCESS_A.
>
> PROCESS_B creates the first thread but not the second.
>
> PROCESS_C creates the second thread but not the first.
>
> PROCESS_D creates both threads.

So by my count four threads are created.

The final `fork` call is a red herring. A new process is created, true, but it immediately terminates as there's no code following the last fork.